# How to do an inverse correlation matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I'm doing a ML project on a wine quality dataset from kaggle. I've made a correlation matrix using the following:

```
corr_features =[]

for i , r in df.corr().iterrows():  
    k=0
    for j in range(len(r)):
        if i!= r.index[k]:
            if r.values[k] >=0.5: #only correlates values with r valus of 0.5 or greater
                corr_features.append([i, r.index[k], r.values[k]])
        k += 1
corr_features

Out[66]:
[['fixed acidity', 'citric acid', 0.6717034347641041],
 ['fixed acidity', 'density', 0.6680472921189711],
 ['citric acid', 'fixed acidity', 0.6717034347641041],
 ['free sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 0.6671819962872733],
 ['total sulfur dioxide', 'free sulfur dioxide', 0.6671819962872733],
 ['density', 'fixed acidity', 0.6680472921189711]]
```

My professor suggested that I create a matrix for the features that correlate inversely, and I'm stumped. I tried using np.linalg.inv but I don't think that will work since the first matrix isn't an array.

Any suggestions are appriciated.

Comment: df.values will return the underlying matrice of your pandas dataframe

Comment: What I think he meant is that he wants you to look at the features that have **negative** correlation. That's how I interpret 'inversely correlated'